# Jackson JsonSerialize annotation not picked up when additional property is added to data class

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I have two data classes and I'm trying to serialize them as follows:

```
data class Test1(@JsonSerialize (using = ToStringSerializer::class) val date: LocalDate, val number: Int)
data class Test2(@JsonSerialize (using = ToStringSerializer::class) val date: LocalDate, val number: Int, val duration: Duration)

class SerializeTest {
    @Test
    fun test(){
        val mapper = ObjectMapper().apply{
            enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            registerModule(kotlinModule())
            registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        }
        val x = Test1(Clock.System.todayAt(TimeZone.UTC), 123)
        val y = Test2(Clock.System.todayAt(TimeZone.UTC), 1, 1.seconds)

        println(mapper.writeValueAsString(x))
        println(mapper.writeValueAsString(y))
    }
}
```

(Note: the LocalDate and Duration types are Kotlin types, not the Java ones)

The output is:

```
{
  "date" : {
    "year" : 2022,
    "dayOfMonth" : 26,
    "month" : "DECEMBER",
    "dayOfWeek" : "MONDAY",
    "dayOfYear" : 360,
    "monthNumber" : 12,
    "value$kotlinx_datetime" : [ 2022, 12, 26 ]
  },
  "number" : 1,
  "duration" : 2000000000
}

{
  "date" : "2022-12-26",
  "number" : 123
}
```

In the second class, ToStringSerializer is clearly not used to serialize the date property. As soon as I remove the duration property, or I change its class to e.g. String, it works as expected.

Why is this?

Comment: Work for me: I get `"date" : "2022-12-26",` in both cases, but then I don't know what libraries you are using for `Clock.System...`
Can you provide the full program?

Comment: What is the package of `Kotlin`'s `LocalDate` class? Is it [kotlinx-datetime](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime)?

Comment: @wasmachien  do you have a solution for this?